# VBA Excel, Cell Self Identification

Tags: excel, vba

I'm Attempting to get each call in A1:E5 to self identify them self among 3 worksheets.  So each will list off as so (Examples:)  Sheet1:$A$3    Sheet1:$A$4    Sheet12:$B$2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim intRowIndex, intColumnIndex, intDimIndex As Integer

'Change Colors/Fonts and Resize
Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).Columns.AutoFit
Columns("A:E").AutoFit


 For intDimIndex = 1 To 3
    For intRowIndex = 1 To 5
        For intColumnIndex = 1 To 5
            Worksheets(intDimIndex).Cells(intRowIndex, Chr(64 + intColumnIndex)).Value = Sheets(intDimIndex).Cells(intRowIndex, Chr(intColumnIndex + 64)).Value = _
            Sheets(intDimIndex).Name & ":$" & Chr(intColumnIndex + 64) & "$" _
            & Str(intRowIndex)
        Next intColumnIndex
    Next intRowIndex
Next intDimIndex
```

Yet the Boxes just fill out as "FALSE"

Comment: The `Sheets(intDimIndex).Cells(intRowIndex, Chr(intColumnIndex + 64)).Value = ` part should have a `&` there, not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing your code to pseudo values shows that you are actually assigning a Boolean value.

`Cell1.Value = Cell2.Value = Cell3.Value`

It's strange that you would do this in a Worksheet_SelectionChange.

It is good to have descriptive names, however, if the names are too long it takes away from the readability of the code.  If you have to scroll up and down or right to left you may want to consider refactoring your code.

As a rule I use x, x1, x2 ... for iterating over rows and y, y1, y2 ... to iterate over columns.  Because I am consistent about it these are very descriptive names.  Whenever you see me use x and x1 I am iterating over two sets of rows.  The first loop is variable is x and the second is x1.

Here you declare three variables intRowIndex are intColumnIndex variant type and intDimIndex is an Integer.

`Dim intRowIndex, intColumnIndex, intDimIndex As Integer`

When you declare a variable and it is not follow by `As` and a DataType then that variable is a variant.  You will be better of declaring all you row variables as long.  I declare column variable as long also even though Integer would do.

`Dim x as long, y as long, w As Integer`

```
'Change Colors/Fonts and Resize
Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).Columns.AutoFit
Columns("A:E").AutoFit


For w = 1 To 3
    For x = 1 To 5
        For y = 1 To 5
            With Worksheets(w)
                .Cells(x, y).Value = .Cells(x, y).Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True)
            End With
        Next y
    Next x
Next w
```